# Combining multiple INSERT statements into one

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO TABLE WEEKS (ID, WK1) SELECT ID, WEEK1 FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100; 
INSERT INTO TABLE WEEKS (ID, WK2) SELECT ID, WEEK2 FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100;
INSERT INTO TABLE WEEKS (ID, WK3) SELECT ID, WEEK3 FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100;
INSERT INTO TABLE WEEKS (ID, WK4) SELECT ID, WEEK4 FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100;
```

Is there a way to combine these statements into one?

Comment: You should actually change your table design. It is not normalized

Comment: What do you get if you combine them into one? You should do what @juergend wrote. Had you done that from start, you wouldn't be looking how to glue all of this into one.

Comment: I upvoted to offset the downvoter. A bad table design does not mean that this is a bad question. Sometimes people inherit code from others and don't have control over the design. They should still be able to ask questions.

Comment: You can have week1 - weekn in tbl1 and as each week goes by an alter table is run to add a new week?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE WEEKS (ID, WK1, WK2, WK3, WK4)
      SELECT ID, WEEK1, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100; 
UNION SELECT ID, NULL, WEEK2, NULL, NULL FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100;
UNION SELECT ID, NULL, NULL, WEEK3, NULL FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100;
UNION SELECT ID, NULL, NULL, NULL, WEEK4 FROM TBL1 WHERE ID = 100;
```

Like others said, this doesn't seem like a good table design. You should look into normalizing your table structure if you can.

Comment: WEEK(1-4) are the columns of the TBL1. They are not a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED for how the original question has been updated:

You can combine these INSERT statements using UNIONS as stated by @adam0101, but it won't be any faster than using 4 INSERT statements.

**Please note that you really should re-design your database to be [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)**. Doing so will reduce duplicate data and improve your database's performance.

Comment: This will only insert one record, whereas the original query inserts 4.

Comment: It was my mistake. It is not a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to consolidate the query, you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE WEEKS (ID, WK1,WK2,WK3,WK4) SELECT ID, 1,2,3,4 FROM TBL1 
WHERE ID = 100;
```

Comment: This will only insert one record, whereas the original query inserts 4

Comment: Pretty much yes, but I am still not sure 4 rows is what he wanted